# If $s=\{2-2x,3+4x^2\}$find the $\text{span}(s)$

Tags: calculus

If

$$
s=\{2-2x,3+4x^2\},
$$

then what is the $\text{span}(s)$? Is it space span or spanning set? I don't have any work to show, because I have no clue how to even approach the problem. Thanks.

Comment: see please answer

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathrm{span}(s)=\{a(2-2x)+b(3+4x^2)\mid a,b\in\boldsymbol R\}=\{4bx^2-2ax+2a+3b\mid a,b\in\boldsymbol R\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

we can represent our list as a  $(1,3/2), (-x,2x^2)$

because  for example in your case $2*(1,3/2)+2*(-x,2*x^2)=(2-2*x,3+4*x^2)$

of course we may choose different numbers in front of $x$   and $x^2$,unfortunately i have not much time to  write combination in detailed,i guess that  you got main point  what you should do and how,good lucks

EDITED general span

$a*(1,3/2)+b*(-x,2x^2)$